# How to fix Azure Kubernetes Services with Terraform 'error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused'?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

What is the cause of 'terraform apply' giving me the error below on my local machine? It seems to run fine on the build server.

I've also checked the related stackoverflow messages:

- Windows Firewall is disabled, thus 80 is allowed on the private network
- config_path in AKS is not used, no kubeconfig seems to be configured anywhere

```
Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

kubernetes_namespace.azurevotefront-namespace: Creating...
kubernetes_service.azurevotefront-metadata: Creating...
kubernetes_deployment.azurevotefront-namespace: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused   
│
│   with kubernetes_namespace.azurevotefront-namespace,
│   on kubernetes.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevotefront-namespace":
│    1: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevotefront-namespace" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to create deployment: Post "http://localhost/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/azurevotefront-namespace/deployments": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
│
│   with kubernetes_deployment.azurevotefront-namespace,
│   on main.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "azurevotefront-namespace":
│    1: resource "kubernetes_deployment" "azurevotefront-namespace" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/azurevotefront-namespace/services": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
│
│   with kubernetes_service.azurevotefront-metadata,
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "kubernetes_service" "azurevotefront-metadata":
│   47: resource "kubernetes_service" "azurevotefront-metadata" {
```

Kubernetes.tf

```json
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevotefront-namespace" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "azurevotefront-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "azurevotefront-value"
    }

    name = "azurevotefront-namespace"
  }
}
```

Provider.tf

```json
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    key = "terraform.tfstate"
    resource_group_name = "MASKED"
    storage_account_name = "MASKED"
    access_key = "MASKED"
    container_name = "MASKED"
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.68"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.4"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id = "MASKED"
  subscription_id = "MASKED"
  client_id = "MASKED"
  client_secret = "MASKED"
  features {}
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `kubernetes` provider configuration. I think by default it tries to create resources on a cluster locally.

Comment: Any idea's how I can create the file config? I've read this but can't figure out how to generate "~/.kube/config".

Comment: You want to generate `~/.kube/config` with terraform on the fly?

Comment: @Jay you can look here how to configure `kubernetes` provider for AKS: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#examples

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I was missing the kubectl config, retrieved it using:  aks get-credentials --name --resource-group [--admin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments you are missing the kubernetes provider config:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```